# What is register reload?

Tags: compiler-construction, register-allocation

I've encountered the term "register reload", but I couldn't find anything about it online except that it's related to register spill. I think I know what a spill is (when the compiler has more live values than it has registers available so it has to store some of them in memory), but what is a reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, asked a colleague and "register reload" is just the term used for the instruction that loads the value back from the spill area into the register, so I guess that's that.